# FF4J does not flip when using AOP annotation @Flip in spring project

Tags: java, spring, ff4j

I've injected `ff4j` following [example](https://github.com/clun/ff4j/tree/master/ff4j-spring-boot-autoconfigure). `Ff4jConfiguration.class`:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public FF4j getFF4j() {
    return new FF4j("ff4j.xml");
}
```

and application loader was also changed:

```
@Import( {..., Ff4jConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter(Ff4jConfiguration.class)
```

my `ff4j.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ff4j xmlns="http://www.ff4j.org/schema/ff4j"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ff4j.org/schema/ff4j http://ff4j.org/schema/ff4j-1.4.0.xsd">
    <features>
        <feature uid="occurrence-logging" enable="false"/>
        <feature uid="check-no-logging" enable="false"/>
        <feature uid="check-logging" enable="true"/>
    </features>
</ff4j>
```

My bean to verify `ff4j`

```
@Component
public class JustToCheck {
    @Autowired
    private FF4j ff4j;

    @Flip(name="occurrence-logging")
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    @Flip(name="check-no-logging")
    public void log2() {
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }

    @Flip(name="check-logging")
    public void log3() {
        System.out.println("hello3");
    }
}
```

In runtime I see `ff4j` bean **injected correctly** with correspond properties:

```
 ff4j.check("check-no-logging")
 > result=false

 ff4j.check("check-logging")
 > result=true
```

I expect method `log2` will be never called, but it is (All used methods were called, none ignored). Can someone help me what I've done wrong here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation `Flip`is meant to be positionned on an **Interface** and not on bean.
The reason is to enforce people to create different implementations for the same method when using AOP. (simpler when cleaning is required later).

I can propose 2 solutions. The first seems obvious but if you don't have multiple implementations...

```
@Component
public class JustToCheck {

    @Autowired
    private FF4j ff4j;
    
    public void log2() {
        if (ff4j.check("check-no-logging")) {
            System.out.println("hello2"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("As check-no-logging is disable... do nothin");
        }
    }
}
```

The second is to indeed use AOP and you have to :

1. Add the Autoproxy located in package `org.ff4j.aop` in your Spring Context. But it's done already by adding autoconfigure dependency.
2. Put `@Flip`annotation on a interface and create different implementations:

Here is a code sample:

```
@Component
public interface JustToCheck {
    @Flip(name="check-no-logging", alterBean="just-to-check")
    void log2();
}

@Component("just-to-check")
public class JustToCheckImpl implements JustToCheck {
   public void log2() {
       System.out.println("hello2");
    }
}

@Component("just-to-check-mock")
public class JustToCheckMock implements JustToCheck {

  public void log2() {
    System.out.println("As check-no-logging is disable... do nothing");
  }
}
```

Bug has been reproduced and the 2 working solutions are available here :
https://github.com/clun/ff4j-samples/tree/master/ff4j-sample-sergii

Comment: I've updated title following your recommendation, thanks.